# No suitable conversion function from std string to const char * exists

Tags: c++, string, c++11, char

I'm using a pre-built library and in order for me to load a texture and display it I have to use this code. I'm looking to load multiple files and store them as a `struct` in an array so they can be called and displayed. I keep getting this error:

> No suitable conversion function from `std` string to const char * exists

when trying to load in the section below.

```
for (int i=0; i<CUTSCENE; i++)
{
    stringstream s;
    int fileNum = i+1;

    string FirstPart = "Textures/GameVideos/Game (";
    string LastPart = ").png";

    s << FirstPart << fileNum << LastPart << endl;
    string fullfileName;
    s >> fullfileName;

    cutSceneMain[i]->texture = new Texture2D();
    cutSceneMain[i]->texture->Load(fullfileName, false);
    cutSceneMain[i]->sourceRect = new Rect(0.0f, 0.0f, 700, 700);
    cutSceneMain[i]->position = new Vector2(0.0f, 0.0f());
}
```

Answer (score 9):

The problem is most probably with the way you call `Load`, a fix is to use `fullfileName.c_str()`:

```
cutSceneMain[i]->texture->Load(fullfileName.c_str(), false);
                                            ^^^^^^^
```

`Load` requires `const char*`